# Finding of specific values in an array C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to find the position of an element in an array, the thing is that when I create the function to return the index of the desired element the if statement does not work. However, if I do it in the main function it works perfectly. I would appreciate if someone could explain me why this is happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int find_index(double vector, double *value, int size_vector);


int main() {
    double vec_eye_x[2]={2323,1}; // center position x two eyes.
    double vec_eye_y[2]={33,2}; // center position y two eyes.
    int index_val=1;
    double *yc_max=std::max_element(vec_eye_y,vec_eye_y+2); // Creating a pointer
    double *yc_min=std::min_element(vec_eye_y, vec_eye_y+2);
    double *xc_max=std::max_element(vec_eye_x,vec_eye_x+2);
    double *xc_min=std::min_element(vec_eye_x, vec_eye_x+2);

    int index=0;
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        if(*xc_min==vec_eye_x[i]){std::cout<<"Works in the main function"<<std::endl;}
    }
    std::cout << "index val: " <<find_index(vec_eye_x, &xc_max,2)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}


int find_index(double vector_x, double *value, int size_vector){
    int index=0;
    for(int i=0; i<size_vector; i++){
        if(*value==vector_x[i]){index=i;}
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Wondering how this would even compile: Your function accepts a single double, but vec_eye_x is an array (which would decay to a pointer). xc_max already *is* a pointer, &xc_max produces a pointer to pointer (`double**`). At very least, turn compiler warnings on (-Wall) and *listen to*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the issues mentioned by Davide, you also have an inconsistency problem: in your "main function" test, your are looking for the position of `*xc_min`; however, the value (to search for) that you pass to `find_index` is `xc_max`!

Here's a working version of your code, with changes annotated with triple-slash (///) comments:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int find_index(double* vector, double* value, int size_vector); /// NOTE: 1st argument shuld be pointer (array)!

int main() {
    double vec_eye_x[2] = { 2323,1 }; // center position x two eyes.
    double vec_eye_y[2] = { 33,2 }; // center position y two eyes.
    int index_val = 1;
    double* yc_max = std::max_element(vec_eye_y, vec_eye_y + 2); // Creating a pointer
    double* yc_min = std::min_element(vec_eye_y, vec_eye_y + 2);
    double* xc_max = std::max_element(vec_eye_x, vec_eye_x + 2);
    double* xc_min = std::min_element(vec_eye_x, vec_eye_x + 2);

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (*xc_min == vec_eye_x[i]) { std::cout << "Works in the main function (" << i << ")" << std::endl; }
    }
    std::cout << "index val: " << find_index(vec_eye_x, xc_min, 2) << std::endl;/// Changed "&xc_max" to "xc_min"
    return 0;
}

int find_index(double* vector_x, double* value, int size_vector) { /// NOTE: 1st argument shuld be pointer (array)!
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_vector; i++) {
        if (*value == vector_x[i]) { index = i; }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Index of that element is simply

```
std::distance(vec_eye_x, xc_max);
```

Or if you insist on pointer arithmetic then

```
xc_max - vec_eye_x;
```

*Note:* `std::distance` is declared in header `<iterator>`

---

If you insist on using your original method with iterating over the array again, then the issue with your code was pointed by @Davide Spataro in their answer. Your first argument to `find_index` is a single `double`, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is far away from even compile because for instance:

- if you want to use `vector_x` inf `find_index` as an array, then `vector_x` needs to be declared as follows: `find_index(double* vector_x,..` (with a star).

A working version of your function could be:

```
int find_index(const double* vector_x, const double value, const int size_vector){
    int index=0;
    for(int i=0; i<size_vector; i++){
        if(value==vector_x[i]){index=i;}
    }
    return index;
}
```

Also please note that your function returns the last occurrence of `value` in `vector_x`. If you just need any index you can speed up your function and return immediately after you find an occurrence.

```
if(value==vector_x[i]){ return i;}
```

As a side note, what happens when `value` is not present in `vector_x`? You return `0` meaning that you found an occurrence at position `0` which is wrong.

Comment: There's little use in const-ness for parameters that are accepted by value...

Comment: @Aconcagua Readability improves. Whoever reads the code knows noone that is purely an input.

Comment: Depends on point of view. As user of the function, I don't care if the function modifies the input or not if it is a copy anyway. Just forces me to read more, so readability even decreased (well, the function should be documented well, of course, not forcing me to read the implementation that possibly is heavy to understand anyway). There might be some use for those modifying the function. Well, but which will happen more often?

Comment: Indeed. point of views. I think code should speak for itself and make the documentation superfluous.  If your implementation is heavy and unreadable the problem is not the documentation or an additional const. =)

Comment: There's some truth about. On the other hand, you don't always have the code available (e. g. if using some dll or pre-compiled static library), so you *rely* on documentation... Highly optimised code, possibly even with inline assembly, is often a hard nut to crack, too...

Answer (score 1):

The variable `vec_eye_x` has an array type. However the corresponding parameter in the function `find_index` has the type double.

Similarly the expression `&xc_max` has the type `double **`  but the corresponding function parameter has the type `double *`.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
size_t find_index( const double *vector, size_t n, double value )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && vector[i] != value ) ++i;

    return i;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
std::cout << "index val: " <<find_index( vec_eye_x, 2, *xc_max )<<std::endl;
```

Pay attention to that there is the standard algorithm `std::find`. You could use it the following way

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//…

std::cout << "index val: " << std::distance( std::begin( vec_eye_x ),
                                             std::find( std::begin( vec_eye_x ), std::end( vec_eye_x ), *xc_max ) )
          << std::endl;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

size_t find_index( const double *vector, size_t n, double value )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && vector[i] != value ) ++i;

    return i;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 2;
    double vec_eye_x[N]={ 2323, 1 }; // center position x two eyes.
    double vec_eye_y[N] = { 33, 2 }; // center position y two eyes.

    auto yc_max = std::max_element( std::begin( vec_eye_y ), std::end( vec_eye_y ) );
    auto yc_min = std::min_element( std::begin( vec_eye_y ), std::end( vec_eye_y ) );
    auto xc_max = std::max_element( std::begin( vec_eye_x ), std::end( vec_eye_x ) );
    auto xc_min = std::min_element( std::begin( vec_eye_x ), std::end( vec_eye_x ) );

    size_t pos = find_index( vec_eye_x, N, *xc_max );     

    if ( pos != N )
    {        
        std::cout << "index val: " << pos << std::endl;
    }

    auto it = std::find( std::begin( vec_eye_x ), std::end( vec_eye_x ), *xc_max );

    if ( it != std::end( vec_eye_x  ) )
    {
        std::cout << "index val: " << std::distance( std::begin( vec_eye_x ), it ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
index val: 0
index val: 0
```